# Why can't Wolfram Alpha calculate $\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{(a-\cos\theta)^2+\sin^2\theta}\ d\theta$?

Tags: definite-integrals, wolfram-alpha

In [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/36983/7982) to *How is the average distance between 2 objects orbiting around a third object calculated?* I had to integrate

$$\int_0^{2 \pi}\sqrt{(a-\cos \theta)^2 + \sin^2 \theta} \ d\theta.$$

I [tried to find the integral analytically with Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+sqrt%28%28a-cos%28x%29%29%5E2+%2B+sin%28x%29%5E2%29+from+0+to+2*pi) but it returned an error message:

> Standard computation time exceeded...

which surprised me; I'd figured that this was known and easily looked-up by the site.

Does this mean that there is no known analytical form for this definite integral? Or for some reason is it particularly challenging?

[image: Wolfram Alpha chokes on a simple definite integral]

Comment: The result is nasty! Assuming $a$ is real, we have $$\fbox{$2 \left(\sqrt{(a-1)^2} E\left(-\frac{4 a}{(a-1)^2}\right)+\sqrt{(a+1)^2} E\left(\frac{4 a}{(a+1)^2}\right)\right)\text{ if }\Re((a-2) a)>-1\land \Re(a (a+2))>-1$}$$

Comment: If you need approximation formulae, let me know.

Comment: @Moo "The result is nasty" is essentially the answer, thanks! ;-)

Comment: @uhoh. The result is not nasty at all.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes of course. I am sure the result is actually quite beautiful. I think the better way to put it is that "[It is a quite long calculation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3761261/why-cant-wolfram-alpha-calculate-int-02-pi-sqrta-cos-theta2-sin2-th?noredirect=1#comment7737328_3761280)" and I'm looking for that being posted as the answer.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+sqrt%28%28a-cos%28x%29%29%5E2+%2B+sin%28x%29%5E2%29+ gives the result immediately for the antiderivative.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici nice! Perhaps this case was borderline and asking for the definite integral just pushed it over the edge. Next time this happens to me (if it ever does) I'll try that, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not an error message but just *"Standard computation time exceeded"*.

What you should have obtained is
$$I=\int_0^{2 \pi}\sqrt{(a-\cos (\theta))^2 + \sin^2 (\theta)} \ d\theta=$$
$$I=2 \left(\sqrt{(a-1)^2} E\left(-\frac{4 a}{(a-1)^2}\right)+\sqrt{(a+1)^2}
   E\left(\frac{4 a}{(a+1)^2}\right)\right)$$ provided, if $a$ is a real, that
$$\Re(a (a+2))>-1\land \Re((a-2) a)>-1$$
where appear ellptic integrals of the second kind.
In fact, this reduces to
$$I=4(a+1)E\left(\frac{4 a}{(a+1)^2}\right)$$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha can certainly handle *lengthy* expressions, so is the reason that getting to this result is a challenge, requiring a large number of steps, substitutions, or dead-ends from which it must back-track and then try something else? I'm really after the "Why...?" here, thanks!

Comment: @uhoh. Take the Pro version. It is just because you have limited ressources with the standard version. It is a quite long calculation.

Comment: okay then "It is a quite long calculation" would help round out an answer to my question, ideally supported in some way. That it is long is probably well known to some, but not to others.

Comment: I've just asked [How does my expression end up as an elliptic integral of the second kind?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3761985/284619)